# Define constant value for tests and another for debug

Tags: ios, swift, preprocessor, kif

I'm using XCode 6.1, Swift and KIF for tests.

Is there any way (like processors) to define a `let` value for debug and another specific to tests environment?

Answer (score 1):

Swift allows for computed-properties at file-scope level, making the following possible:

```
var testIsRunning = false

var isDebugging: Bool
{
    return testIsRunning ? false : true
}
```

You could set `testIsRunning` to `true` in your test-case's `-setUp` method.